# Nginx Load balancer not working

Tags: nginx

I have 2 servers A and B, on Server A i have nginx installed
below is my config file loacted at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and configured as below

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;


        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

    upstream sendforward {
                server Server_IP_B:9000;
        }


       server {
        #access_log off;
        server_name my_server_name;
        listen 443;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        location / {

            proxy_pass http://sendforward;
            proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

      }
}
```

when i send message to Server A on port 443 it writes to 'access_log' file but doesn't forward message to Server B.
I also check by ubuntu command 'nc - l 9000' and wireshark by filtering 'tcp.port==9000'.

I didn't get why it is happening or whether i miss in configuration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining your upstream before your proxy pass?

i also think you shoud remove the trailing slash of your proxypass
so http://sendforward instead of http://sendforward/

Comment: Thank's for reply i tried both defining upstream before proxy_pass and http://sendforward but doesn't work. –

Comment: i also notice you are missing a closing bracket } after upstream. but i presume this is only a partial config file

Comment: yes it was partial, now i have posted full  nginx.conf file.

Comment: if there is only one server directive you can try the following
**listen 443;** -> change to -> **listen  443 default_server ssl;**

else **listen 443 ssl;** Might work

Comment: configured nginx but the when i do apache bench the load flows only in localhost:3000; why so ? my upstream configuration file is like this          <pre> <code> upstream project 
{ server localhost:3000;
 server localhost:4002; 
server localhost:4003; }                                                                       server { listen 80; listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server; location / { proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; } location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ { expires 168h; # expires 30d; add_header Vary Accept-Encoding; access_log off; } location /muser { expires 10m; } }